# Find the limit of a function using the definition

Tags: limits, functions

I want to prove the limit of the function sqrt(x) equals 2 using the definition of the limit of a function.

The definition of the limit of a function is: Let I be an open interval that contains the point c and suppose f is a function defined on I, except possibly at the point c. Then f has limit L at c if for each e>0, there exists a number q>0 such that |f(x)-L|

So far, I have the following completed: Let e>0 be given. We must find q>0 such that |sqrt(x)-2|

I have completed these proofs when the function is a polynomial, but I am a little confused of where to go with this problem next. If anyone is willing to assist me, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: the limit of $\sqrt x$ as $x$ approaches what? I (or you?) do not seem to understand what the questions is.

Comment: Is the given problem "To show $\sqrt{x} \to 2$" as $x \to 4$ ?

Comment: Yes,the problem is asking to show √x→2" as x→4 using the limit definition

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

When $x$ closed to $4$, then

$|\sqrt{x}-2|=\frac{|x-4|}{\sqrt{x}+2}\leq\frac{|x-4|}{2}$

So given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon)>0$ ($1$ is chosen to make sure $x$ is bounded away from $0$).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean $\lim\limits_{x\to4}\sqrt{x}=2$ then the question would read

for a fixed $\varepsilon$, can we find a $\delta$ such that $|x-4|<\delta$ implies that $|2-\sqrt{x}|<\varepsilon $?

Start by choosing $\varepsilon>0$.

If $0<x<4$ then $|\sqrt{x}-2|=2-\sqrt{x}<\varepsilon \implies (2-\varepsilon)^2 < x$.

If $4<x$ then $|\sqrt{x}-2|=\sqrt{x}-2<\varepsilon \implies (2+\varepsilon)^2 > x$.

I think you can figure out the rest. :)